# Bot still waiting after OAuthPrompt

Tags: c#, botframework

I have the following code:

```
public class MainDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
        protected readonly ILogger Logger;
        protected int counter = 0;
        protected bool HaveToken = false;
        protected static string Token = "";
  

        public MainDialog(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<MainDialog> logger)
            : base(nameof(MainDialog))
        {   
            //cache the config from appstettings.json for later usage in LUIS & QnAMaker.
            Configuration = configuration;
            Logger = logger;

            AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
              nameof(OAuthPrompt),
               new OAuthPromptSettings
               {
                   ConnectionName = Configuration["ConnectionName"],
                   Text = "Bitte melden sie sich an.",
                   Title = "Login",
                   Timeout = 3000,
               }));

            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            //Adding Dialogs and giving the Dialogs the config info for the QnAMaker connection.
            AddDialog(new HelpDialog(Configuration, logger));
            AddDialog(new SpellingDialog(Configuration, logger));
            AddDialog(new CreateTeamDialog(Configuration, logger));
            AddDialog(new DIGASDialog(Configuration, logger));
            AddDialog(new GreetingDialog(Configuration, logger));
            AddDialog(new OnboardingDialog(Configuration, logger));
            //AddDialog(new LoginDialog(Configuration, logger));
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                PromptStepAsync,
                LoginStepAsync,
                ProcessStepAsync,
                IntroStepAsync,
                ActStepAsync,
                FinalStepAsync
            }));
            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);

        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt),null, cancellationToken);
          
           
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (HaveToken)
            {
                return await stepContext.NextAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            
            if(stepContext.Result.GetType() == typeof(CancellationToken) )
            {
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
            }
            try
            {
                var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
                Token = tokenResponse.Token;
                HaveToken = true;
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You are now logged in."), cancellationToken);
                //await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Your token is: {tokenResponse.Token}"), cancellationToken);

                //await OAuthhelper.ListMeAsync(stepContext.Context, tokenResponse);

                return await stepContext.NextAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
               
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Login was not successful please try again.   " + x.Message), cancellationToken);
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
            }
             

        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ProcessStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (HaveToken)
            {
                return await stepContext.NextAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            if (stepContext.Result != null)
            {
                // We do not need to store the token in the bot. When we need the token we can
                // send another prompt. If the token is valid the user will not need to log back in.
                // The token will be available in the Result property of the task.
                var tokenResponse = stepContext.Result as TokenResponse;

                // If we have the token use the user is authenticated so we may use it to make API calls.
                if (tokenResponse?.Token != null)
                {
                    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Your token is: {tokenResponse.Token}"), cancellationToken);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("We couldn't log you in. Please try again later."), cancellationToken);
            }

            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> IntroStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await stepContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ActStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var intentDetails = new QueryDetails();

            // Call LUIS and gather any potential booking details. (Note the TurnContext has the response to the prompt.)
            intentDetails = stepContext.Result != null
                    ?
                await LuisHelper.ExecuteLuisQuery(Configuration, Logger, stepContext.Context, cancellationToken)
                    :
                new QueryDetails();

            switch (intentDetails.Intent)
            {
                case "Hilfe":
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(HelpDialog), intentDetails, cancellationToken);
                case "Schreibweise_Ausdruck":
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(SpellingDialog), intentDetails, cancellationToken);
                case "Team_erstellen":
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(CreateTeamDialog), intentDetails, cancellationToken);
                case "DIGAS":
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(DIGASDialog), intentDetails, cancellationToken);
                case "Begrueßung":
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(GreetingDialog), intentDetails, cancellationToken);
                case "Onboarding":
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OnboardingDialog), intentDetails, cancellationToken);
                default:
                    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("Das habe ich nicht verstanden.");
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(HelpDialog), intentDetails, cancellationToken);
                    
            }
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Vielen Dank."), cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }

        public static string getToken()
        {
            return Token;
        }
    }
```

After the Promptstep, the next step does not run until I give input. I more or less copied the AuthBot sample from Microsoft and modified it a little.

In the Promptstep the user authenticates himself, but after the prompt vanishes the Bot waits for more input instead of jumping to the next step.

The bot, where I copied the code from:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs

I could not test the sample, because it doesn't run on it's own.
When I testet my bot in the Emulator with ngrok tunneling, the token was recieved but the bot just exits and waits for input.

Here is what happens:
[image: This is how it looks in chat]

Why is LoginStep not starting after the prompt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A lot of clarification is needed before we'll be able to help you, so please edit this information into your question. What channel are you using? Please link to the sample you've copied your code from and explain how you've modified it. Does the sample work as you expect without your modifications? How have you determined that LoginStep isn't running? Have you set breakpoints in your code and ran it in debug mode? Please provide screenshots of your authentication process so we can better understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: I am still working on this. I edited the information. Hope this helps somehow. I have not found any solution. When I deploy to azure and do a test in the webchat it just grabs the token from my browser...

Comment: I wonder if the problem is that you're using a Teams sample in Emulator. Have you read [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication) and tried [this sample](https://aka.ms/v4cs-bot-auth-sample)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add ChoicePrompt too:

```
AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
```

Comment: How would this help my problem?